# Не линкуется boost

Tags: boost, c++

Использую Visual Studio 2008, скачиваю [boost](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.55.0/), а именно `boost_1_55_0-msvc-9.0-64.exe`.
Начинаю собирать, получаю следующую ошибку: "тип компьютера модуля x64 противоречит типу целевого компьютера x86"
Какую версию мне необходимо качать?

Answer (score 1):

Если вы используете 32-х битный компилятор, то и версия boost вам нужна соответствующая.
Выберите [boost_1_55_0-msvc-8.0-32.exe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.55.0/boost_1_55_0-msvc-8.0-32.exe/download)